# Is there any text entry required in-game, after character creation?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

I'm thinking about re-mapping some or all of the controls in The Elder Scrolls: Arena.  I'm currently running under DOSBox, and the only way I can think of to do this would be to re-map the keyboard via the VM's config file.  However, if I do this, I expect it will end up affecting *all* of my keyboard usage during the session - not just the in-game controls.

If the only time I *need* to type text freely is during character creation, I consider that an acceptable sacrifice.  Is this the case, or are there quests or other significant interactions which require more text entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are some specific parts of the game that act as a copy protection routine, requiring player to enter particular costs of certain spells, which are only present in game's manual. I think this only requires entering numbers though.

Comment: There's a point at the end of the first dungeon that requires an entered code. It's mentioned in the arena download, and a text file is included which lists the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Later quests contain riddles that require you to enter the answer before a door opens.

Also, if you create your own spells, you need to give them a name ("my fireball 1").

However, these moments are so rare that it should be possible to play without text entry, and then switch configurations when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've also remapped the WASD keys to the arrow keys, and what took some time getting used to is writing the name of my saves. I had to replace the real arrow keys with WASD and use those when I want to type any of these letters in my save's name.

I guess it's not strictly required to type anything in here, but I find it pretty important to rename saves so you know which one is the newest for example.

As a general rule of thumb, when you remap a key using the DOSBox mapper, say when mapping X to Y, also map Y to X to still be able to type both letters but also have a modified control scheme like you want.